# Convert Excel Function to VBA Code for automation

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert my **excel** formulas into **VBA** to automate a spreadsheet that I do daily.

How would I alter the following to work in VBA?

```
=IF(OR(A2="Story",A2="Task"),((J2+SUMIFS($J:$J,$D:$D,C2))/3600)/8,"")

=IF(OR(A2="Story",A2="Task"),((K2+SUMIFS($K:$K,$D:$D,C2))/3600)/8,"")

=IF(OR(A2="Story",A2="Task"),IF(OR(E2="Done",E2="Closed"),O2,IF(N2<M2,((M2-N2)/M2)*O2,0)),"")
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro?

Comment: Hi all, I used the following, which worked well: 

Worksheets("GEP").Range("M2").Formula = "=IF(OR(A2=""Story"",A2=""Task""),((J2+SUMIFS($J:$J,$D:$D,C2))/3600)/8,"""")"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the formulas in VBA in simple way like that

```
Sub Test()
With Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=IF(OR(A2=""Story"",A2=""Task""),((J2+SUMIFS($J:$J,$D:$D,C2))/3600)/8,"""")"
End With
End Sub
```

Notice the strings should be double quoted ""Story"" ..
And you can assign the range that you would like to insert the formulas in.
And also you can add a line to get only the values instead of the formulas

```
Sub Test()
With Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=IF(OR(A2=""Story"",A2=""Task""),((J2+SUMIFS($J:$J,$D:$D,C2))/3600)/8,"""")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```